# setter and getter methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, setter, getter

I know that you use @synthesize to create setter and getter methods, which makes things easier because then you don't have to write your own.

There are certain places where you have to use self.property instead of just property in order to make use of the setter and getter methods, such as in dealloc and initWithCoder.

This tells me that these setter and getter methods are doing something else that's important, besides making it easier for you to set and get a variable. What are they doing and how do they do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're doing whatever you told them to do in the `@property` statement or your own implementation, if you chose to write one.  Most often, the reason for using the accessors rather than directly modifying instance variables is to avoid memory leaks.  Imagine an `NSString` instance variable declared with

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
@synthesize myString;
```

These lines generate an accessor that correctly calls `release` and `retain` when you want to change the `myString` property of an object.  If you didn't call the accessor, you could potentially leak the old value, unless you were careful to do the memory management yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your base precept:

> There are certain places where you have to use self.property instead of
>   just property in order to make use of the setter and getter methods, such as
>   in dealloc and initWithCoder.
>
> This tells me that these setter and getter methods are doing something
>   else that's important...

isn't quite correct. The difference here is that using self.propertyname specifically invokes the getter/setter when used within that class, where directly using propertyname doesn't - it accesses the instance variables directly.

Per @Carl Good practice is that you use the getter/setter sequence everywhere you absolutely can, as that keeps you pretty safe from missing a corner case of memory management.

Answer (score 2):

I second what @heckj and @Carl said, but must add one more point.

**In general** it is **not** safe to use accessors in either `init` or `dealloc`. The problem is that you class might be subclassed, the accessors might be overridden. Then these accessors might access other properties of your class or a subclass. This might lead to crashes:

- In the case of `init` these haven't been initialized yet (because in `init` the first call you do is `[super init]`).
- In the case of `dealloc` these have already been freed (because in `dealloc` the last call you do is `[super dealloc]`).

**In practice** you *may* use accessors in `init` and `dealloc`. Under two premisses:

- You know what you're doing. (see above)
- You control all maybe inheriting code. (does not apply for frameworks, etc.)